# boost 1.55 asio tcp cpp03 chat_server example memory leaks

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

i hope someone could give me a clue where to investigate...

i'm running the chat_server example from boost

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/chat/chat_server.cpp

on visual studio 2010, windows 10 and i downloaded boost binaries from :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0-msvc-10.0-32.exe/download

i used a script to simulate 30 tcp clients, each thread behavior basically:

1. connect to tcp server
2. start a loop
3. send a message to tcp server
4. receive a message from tcp server
5. sleep
6. back to step 2

the strange fact is when i use windows task manager to monitor the memory consumption. The numbers from columns **private working set** and **shared working set** remains "stable" for almost 18 minutes and after that the values of **private working set** starts to increase almost 5 MB by minute.

So my doubts are:

1. Does anyone ever seen anything similar before?
2. What could cause this?

Regards

Comment: I don't understand why all deque implementations seem unable to cope with ... double ended queues. I'll probably bounty this question to see if some can come up with an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The server retains chat history, but only the 100 most recent messages in a "ringbuffer" (actually a `deque<chat_message>`).

Indeed testing with a large number of clients doing a lot of chatting:

```
(for c in {00..99}; do for a in {001..999}; do sleep .1; echo "Client $c message $a"; done | ./chat_client localhost 6767& done)
```

Shows a memory increase:

[image]

The breakdown indicates it's due to allocations from `deliver` for `_write_msgs_` which is also a queue.

```
3.4 GiB: std::deque<chat_message, std::allocator<chat_message> >::_M_push_back_aux(chat_message const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
3.4 GiB: chat_session::deliver(chat_message const&) (stl_deque.h:1526)
```

It doesn't logically grow, though, so it would appear there's some unfortunate behaviour.

Let's investigate:

On a total test run (shown above) the max write queue depth for any session is 60.

Upon restart of all the client (without reloading the server), the queue depth increases to 100 immediately for obvious reasons (all clients get the full history of 100 items delivered at once)¹.

#### Add `shrink_to_fit`

Adding a call to `shrink_to_fit` after each `pop_front` call in `chat_session` doesn't make the the behaviour any better (apart from the fact that c++03 doesn't have `shrink_to_fit` of course).

#### Use a different container

Dropping in a `boost::circular_buffer` instead of the `std::deque`, strangely reaches a queue depth of 100 easily, even on the first run, but it **does** change the memory profile ***dramatically***:

[image]

Clearly, there's something suboptimal about using deque as... a double-ended queue o.O That's very surprising. I'll try with libc++ instead:

#### Using libc++ instead

Interestingly, with `std::deque<>` and shrink-to-fit libc++ shows a different - still bad -curve. Note also it report ever-growing `_write_msgs_` queue depths. Somehow it behaves really differently... o.O

[image]

---

¹ Even thought the client immediately start cackling as well, the queue depth doesn't go beyond 100 - so throughput is still fine.

Comment: I've located the culprit and found a trivial drop-in replacement that removes the problem. Still looking http://livecoding.tv/sehe

Comment: Sidenote: Never mind the ever-growing queue depth is an observer effect (running under massif memory profiler slows it down enough to build up undelivered messages).

Comment: Running things through http://milianw.de/blog/heaptrack-a-heap-memory-profiler-for-linux now

Comment: Summarizing: deque seems to be a bad fit (std::deque in both libc++ and libstdc++ as well as Boost Container's `deque<>`). Using `shrink_to_fit` doesn't really seem to change anything. Using `boost::circular_buffer` knocks the socks off anything else - gcc a little more accurately than clang it seems. Sidenote: profiling still tricky without influencing the process being profiled.

Comment: Recorded livestream of my efforts  in case you want to peek over my shoulder: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/why-is-asios-chat-sample-leaking-memory/ (starts around ~27:00 mark)

Comment: sehe: Thank you for your help and your time. I will follow your suggestion and do it with boost::circular_buffer.