# C++ vector with wrapping random access?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, vector, stl

What I would really like is a container class in C++, which is exactly like the STL vector class in every way, except that the [] operator has wrapping behaviour. For example:

```
vector<int>  myVec;
myVec.push_back(5);
myVec.push_back(10);
myVec.push_back(15);

cout << myVec[ 5] << endl;   // would output 15
cout << myVec[ 1] << endl;   // would output 10
cout << myVec[-2] << endl;   // would output 10
```

Does such a container already exist, or is it possible to overload or redefine the [] operator in the vector template?

I have seen the [Boost circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html), and it does not behave in this way.

Comment: It would so easy to do when operator dot will make its way to the standard.

Comment: So `at` would retain its vector semantics? Also, why does `myVec[ 1]` print `5` instead of `10`? What happens if the vector is empty?

Answer (score 3):

> Does such a container already exist

Not in standard library at least.

> is it possible to overload or redefine the [] operator in the vector template?

No, you cannot overload or redefine [] operator of `std::vector`.

It is certainly possible to write a wrapper with an overloaded `T& operator[](int pos)` that has the behaviour that you describe. Like this:

```
T& operator[](int pos) {
    std::vector<T>::size_type fancy_pos =
        pos < 0 ? data.size() + pos
                : pos - 1;
    return data[fancy_pos];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ indices for containers start from 0.

You could wrap the standard container std::vector in a class and overload operator [] such a way that the index is calculated like `index = index % size()` or `index %= size()`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a cyclic buffer or a circular buffer.

Boost has them:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html

They are sometimes **vastly** better performing than e.g. rolling your own with std::deque, see this sample from ASIO:

- [boost 1.55 asio tcp cpp03 chat_server example memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772823/boost-1-55-asio-tcp-cpp03-chat-server-example-memory-leaks/34778818#34778818)

---

### Update

I maintain boost::circular_buffer is probably what you /should want/ - because it abstracts away the "how" for most tasks that you'd usually want this for. However, it's dead simple to create your own adaptor type:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b59df10fc400315)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>

namespace mylib {
    template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T> >
    struct circular : Container {
        using Container::Container;
        using Container::operator =;

        auto& operator[](int i) const {
            // mixed signed/unsigned modulo is undefined
            while (i<0) i += Container::size();
            return Container::operator[](i % Container::size());
        }

        auto& operator[](int i) {
            while (i<0) i += Container::size();
            return Container::operator[](i % Container::size());
        }
    };
}

#include <iostream>

template <typename Whatever>
void test(Whatever const& data) {
    std::cout << data[ 5] << ", "; // would output 15
    std::cout << data[ 1] << ", "; // would output 10
    std::cout << data[-2] << std::endl; // would output 10
}

#include <string>
#include <deque>
int main() {
    test(mylib::circular<int>                                   { 5, 10, 15                }); 
    test(mylib::circular<std::string>                           { "five", "teen", "fiteen" }); 
    test(mylib::circular<std::string, std::deque<std::string> > { "five", "teen", "fiteen" }); 
    test(mylib::circular<int, std::deque<float> >               { 5, 10, 15                }); 
}
```

Prints:

```
15, 10, 10
fiteen, teen, teen
fiteen, teen, teen
15, 10, 10
```

Comment: As I said in my question, I have seen the Boost circular buffer, and it does not implement the behaviour I want.

Comment: I did not see that. However, then it's simply this: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b59df10fc400315) (note the subtleties around the modulo operator)

Comment: The main reason I cannot use the Boost circular buffer is that it doesn't accept indices outside the range [0..n-1].

Comment: Since I'm a bit unfamilar with templates: Is this essentially doing what I wanted? It's 'overriding' the container's [] operator, and still providing all of the rest of the container's interface?

Comment: Not strange. You didn't mention any version. I can easily make it compile in any version, it'll just be slightly less generic: [c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/553e82b083dd073c) or [c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d37a6e65b86d611). The version in my answer was [c++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b59df10fc400315). Note that the C++03 does not automatically expose **all** of the original interface (because inheriting constructors didn't exist. You may want to add the constructor(s) you require)